# NxRx-Data custom DataService does not use DataSeviceConfiguration

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-data

I extended the DefaultDataService like this:

```ts
    @Injectable()
    export class DidDocumentDataService extends DefaultDataService<DidDocument> {
      constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator) {
        super("DidDocument", http, httpUrlGenerator, defaultDataServiceConfig);
      }

      getById(): Observable<DidDocument> {
        return this.http.get("/identifiers").pipe(
          map(res => res["didDocument"])
        );
      }
    }
```

The `app-store.module.ts` is setup like this:

```ts
// this used to work before overriting the DefaultDataService
export const defaultDataServiceConfig: DefaultDataServiceConfig = {
  root: `${HOST}/1.0/`
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig),
    ... // other store related imports
  ],
  providers: [
    DidDocumentDataService,
    { provide: DefaultDataServiceConfig, useValue: defaultDataServiceConfig }
  ],
  declarations: [StoreComponent],
  exports: [StoreComponent]
})
export class AppStoreModule {
  constructor(
    private entityDataService: EntityDataService,
    private didDocService: DidDocumentDataService
  ) {
    this.entityDataService.registerService("DidDocument", this.didDocService);
  }
}
```

Before I extended the DefaultDataService, the `defaultDataServiceConfig` was used and the requests were triggered against the custom `root`. Now every request hit `localhost` (seems to just use the current host).

The `AppStoreModule` is not a lazy-loaded module and is loaded in the `AppModule`. The component which is triggering the request is the `StoreComponent`. My first guess is that something is not happening in the order I expect it.

When is the `CustomDataService` with the `CustomConfiguration` created and does overwriting the Service only work in lazy-loaded modules?

### Solution

I set the absolute URL in the httpClient directly and also pass the identiefer to the `getById` method:

```ts
getById(id: string): Observable<DidDocument> {
  return this.http.get(`${HOST}/1.0/identifiers/${id}`).pipe(
    map(res => res["didDocument"])
  );
}
```

Comment: https://ngrx.io/api/data/DefaultDataServiceConfig ... can't you just use `{ root: HOST, entityHttpResourceUrls: { DidDocument: { entityResourceUrl: '/1.0/identifiers/'} }`? [provide-a-custom-configuration](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice#provide-a-custom-configuration)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but that doesn't work. I guess it's because the `DefaultDataServiceConfig` is not passed to a `CustomDataService` which overwrites the `DefaultDataService`.

Comment: are you sure?... [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crdbah-ngrx-data-config), needed to specify full url for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is probably in this code :

```js
getById(): Observable<DidDocument> {
  return this.http.get("/identifiers").pipe(
    map(res => res["didDocument"])
  );
}
```

In this case, even if the `DefaultDataServiceConfig` is correctly set with the correct `url`, this code is overriding the `GET` url.

```js
http.get("/identifiers")
```

is equivalent to

```js
http.get("http://localhost/identifiers")
```

(if your dev app is serving on `localhost`)

You should either set absolute `url` or use ancestor methods of `DefaultDataService` with `super` :

```js
getById(): Observable<DidDocument> {
  return super.getById(id).pipe(
    map(res => res["didDocument"])
  );
}
```

You can find more details inside [official doc](https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-dataservice#custom-entitydataservice), with this code snippet example :

```js
@Injectable()
export class HeroDataService extends DefaultDataService<Hero> {
  constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: HttpUrlGenerator, logger: Logger) {
    super('Hero', http, httpUrlGenerator);
    logger.log('Created custom Hero EntityDataService');
  }

  getById(id: string | number): Observable<Hero> {
    return super.getById(id).pipe(map(hero => this.mapHero(hero)));
  }
}
```

Comment: I went for the solution to set the URL in the httpClient, because it doesn't follow the ngrx-data convention. See edit in the question.